# How to organize unit tests and e2e tests in AngularJS?

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing, protractor, angularjs-e2e, e2e-testing

I need to organize unit tests and end to end tests for my JavaScript Single Page Application. I'm using AngularJS Protractor/Cucumber for e2e testing and Chai for unit tests.

I have e2e and unit tests in two different folders (`unit` and `e2e` folder) and I'm currently not taking advantage of the [page object](https://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/PageObjects) design patterm. The files are unstructured and don't share a lot of code, so I'm repeating myself many times.

I recognize this approach doesn't scale up

Is there a best practice to reorganize the tests in such a way I write the least amount of code, keeping the test code DRY?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First of all, *you should definitely switch to using the Page Object pattern* and keep your page objects under a separate directory - I think it's recommended to call the directory `po`.

Here is a sample for you, the project structure we currently have:

```
$ cd e2e
$ tree -L 1
.
├── config
├── db
├── helpers
├── mocks
├── po
└── specs
```

`config` is special directory where we keep our `protractor` configs - there could be multiple configs - for instance, for local testing and for testing on, say, `BrowserStack`.

`helpers` is, basically, our "libs"/"utils" directory. We keep custom jasmine matchers, additional "helper" modules with helper functions. Also, we have `localStorage` and `sessionStorage` modules that are convenient wrappers around `window.localStorage` and `window.sessionStorage` objects.

`mocks` is a directory where we keep [`protractor-http-mock` mocks](https://github.com/atecarlos/protractor-http-mock).

`po` is a directory where Page Objects are defined. Each Page Object in a separate file.

`specs` is where all of our specs live - they are organized into subdirectories logically.

---

Some of the `helpers` libraries are [made globally available via `global`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31208642/771848), example:

```
onPrepare: function () {
     global.helpers = require("../helpers/helpers.js");
     // ...
},
```

Also, to make the helpers and po import more convenient and avoid traversing the directories up in the tree and to better handle the nestedness, we've switched to using `requirePO` and `requireHelper` helper function suggested by @Michael Radionov, see:

- [Using require with relative paths](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31491952/using-require-with-relative-paths)

I also really like the idea, proposed by @finspin, to make a node package out of each Page Object.

Comment: do you have any example of Page Object?

Comment: @GianlucaGhettini yup, we basically follow what is suggested here: https://github.com/angular/protractor/blob/master/docs/page-objects.md.

Comment: does it make sense to have something like page objects for unit tests as well?

Comment: @ganqqwerty I don't think so. Page objects help to abstract away the UI, split your application UI into convenient objects to work with in your tests. In unit tests you have a direct access to the source code and there is no UI to build abstractions on top of. Hope that helps. Thanks.