# protractor import javascript to typescript tests

Tags: javascript, typescript, protractor

I have protractor running with typescript and I'm trying to follow the steps on the link 
[Using require with relative paths](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31491952/using-require-with-relative-paths/31495707#answer-31624445)
so i can test drag and drop with native javascript from this repo https://gist.github.com/druska/624501b7209a74040175 because there is an issue with Chromedriver and it's not working.

Package.json

```
"dependencies": {
        "@types/jasmine": "^3.5.10",
        "@types/node": "^13.11.0",
        "dragndrop": "./src/utils/functions/dragndrop/",
        "protractor": "^5.4.4",
        "typescript": "^3.8.3"
    },
```

Package.json of the module

```
{
    "name": "dragndrop",
    "version": "0.1.1",
    "description": "Drag and drop object",
    "main": "./index.js",
    "dependencies": {}
}
```

This is what I have in my code

```
var DragAndDrop = require('dragndrop');
var dragAndDropFn = new DragAndDrop();
...
browser.executeScript(dragAndDropFn, elem2, elem1);
```

When I run the test I get

```
E/launcher - Error: Error: Cannot find module 'dragndrop'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:636:15)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:562:25)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:692:17)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:25:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Work\GIT\OSM\Web\temp\src\test-suites\feature\routes-planning\routes-planning-list.spec.js:17:19)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:778:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:789:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:653:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:593:12)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:585:3)
```

Can someone tell what do I need to do/change in order to use the javascript module?

Thanks in advance

Comment: why do you try to include it as a module ? since the file is in the project ? kinda confused...

Comment: Because If I try to include in the test file using require it doesn't work

Comment: You dont need to make it in a module, which to be included in a package. Please introduce yourself to basic typescript/javascript code implementaton. You can make it in a class, module .. to be static .. to be global function etc...

Comment: I try to include in the test file using require like this 
```var dragAndDropFn = require('./native_js_drag_and_drop_helper.js');```
it doesn't work